Cell strength - why is an animal's body so strong?
A cell membrane consists of a double layer of phospholipids - to my mind a thin film of grease, if you will excuse my wildly unsophisticated understanding. It doesn't seem to be enough to convey the sort of mechanical strength that an animal body has, so why is, for example, the human body able to stay together rather than fall apart?

Possible duplicate: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/88965/27148

Because the phospholipid membrane is augmented by other structures and materials created by the cells, such as collagen and keratin. Without these, you are indeed correct in that animals would just disintegrate.
